# Showing a widget and hiding all other widgets by binding ComboboxSelected

Tags: python, tkinter, combobox

I am new to python and GUI-Thinker. I'm learning about how to switch windows on GUI using Tkinker as UI, and python as a programming language.

I followed this guideline [Switch between two frames in tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546050/switch-between-two-frames-in-tkinter) to switch frames in thinker and it worked.

Then, I'm trying to show widgets and hide all other widgets using `bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>"`. But when I choose `Monthly` option, widgets as I set under `DeleteOptions` condition didn't show up. The same thing to `Period` option, widgets as I set under `DeleteOptions` condition didn't show up.

My Code:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import font as tkfont
from tkcalendar import DateEntry

class SampleApp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.title_font = tkfont.Font(family='Helvetica', size=18, weight="bold", slant="italic")

        # the container is where we'll stack a bunch of frames
        # on top of each other, then the one we want visible
        # will be raised above the others
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (StartPage, PageOne):
            page_name = F.__name__
            frame = F(parent=container, controller=self)
            self.frames[page_name] = frame

            # put all of the pages in the same location;
            # the one on the top of the stacking order
            # will be the one that is visible.
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame("StartPage")

    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        '''Show a frame for the given page name'''
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()


class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="This is the start page", font=controller.title_font)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Go to Page One",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame("PageOne"))
        button1.pack()
        
class PageOne(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="This is page 1", font=controller.title_font)
        label.grid()

        button = tk.Button(self, text="Go to the start page",
                           command=lambda: controller.show_frame("StartPage"))
        button.grid()

        def DeleteOptions():
            if SVcmb_Delete.current()=="Monthly":
                HideDeleteOptions()
                lblMonthly.grid(row=4)
                SVcmb_Monthly.grid(row=4, column=1)

            if SVcmb_Delete.current()=="Period":
                HideDeleteOptions()
                lblFrom.grid(row=4)
                txtFrom.grid(row=4, column=1)
                lblTo.grid(row=5)
                txtTo.grid(row=5, column=1)

        lblSV_Search=tk.Label(self,text="Delete by")
        lblSV_Search.grid(row=3)

        SVcmb_Delete=ttk.Combobox(self,state="readonly",justify=CENTER,font=("times new roman",15))
        SVcmb_Delete["values"]=("Select","Monthly","Period")
        SVcmb_Delete.grid(row=3,column=1)
        SVcmb_Delete.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", lambda event:DeleteOptions)

        def HideDeleteOptions():
            lblMonthly.grid_forget()
            SVcmb_Monthly.grid_forget()
            lblFrom.grid_forget()
            txtFrom.grid_forget()
            lblTo.grid_forget()
            txtTo.grid_forget()

        lblMonthly=tk.Label(self,text="Monthly")
        
        SVcmb_Monthly=ttk.Combobox(self,state="readonly",values=[1,2,3],justify=CENTER)
        
        lblFrom=tk.Label(self,text="From")
        
        txtFrom=DateEntry(self,selectmode='day',date_pattern='mm/dd/y')
        
        lblTo=tk.Label(self,text="To")
        
        txtTo=DateEntry(self,selectmode='day',date_pattern='mm/dd/y')
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SampleApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

On page one. I'm looking for a way like when I chose `Monthly` option, all widgets under `DeleteOptions` condition show up and all widgets of `Period` option are hidden as I set under `DeleteOptions` condition. The same thing to `Period` option, all widgets under `DeleteOptions` condition show up and all widgets of `Monthly` option are hidden as I set under `DeleteOptions` condition.

Please help me. Thank you so much.

Comment: I edited the post. Please help me. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with your code. This first is with your `lambda` expression:

```
SVcmb_Delete.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", lambda event:DeleteOptions)
```

is wrong because it doesn't actually *call* the `DeleteOptions()` function the way it's written.

Instead, do it like this:

```
SVcmb_Delete.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", lambda event: DeleteOptions())
```

The second problem is with your use of the `SVcmb_Delete.current()` method *in* the `DeleteOptions()` function because it returns the *index* of the the current entry text, not the entry text itself. To obtain that, you should use the `get()` method. With that correction made the function should look like something like this:

```
    def DeleteOptions():
        if SVcmb_Delete.get() == "Monthly":
            HideDeleteOptions()
            lblMonthly.grid(row=4)
            SVcmb_Monthly.grid(row=4, column=1)

        if SVcmb_Delete.get() == "Period":
            HideDeleteOptions()
            lblFrom.grid(row=4)
            txtFrom.grid(row=4, column=1)
            lblTo.grid(row=5)
            txtTo.grid(row=5, column=1)
```

**Lastly** I also strongly suggest that you read and start following the [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) to make your code more readable.